# OpenStreetMap Requests with Unprecise GPS Position from QtLocation

Tags: c++, qt, openstreetmap, osrm

I am using OSM (OpenStreetMap) plugin for Qt 5.9, to make route calculation in my desktop application.

I have an OSRM local server running that receives the requests from the application.

I noticed a weird flickering in route calculations, and found out that the request hitting the server side does not have the precise GPS coordinates that I passed to the QGeoRoutingManager::calculateRoute request.

[image]

The coordinates are only 3-4 decimal places, while the original request had 7 decimal places for the GPS points.

This imprecision causes a drift in position (causing often placement on the other direction of the road), and thus result in a jump in route calculation.

Is there some way to set the precision?

Comment: Sorry, the image does not to seem uploaded correctly, this is the request logged on the OSRM server side: [info] 07-12-2017 15:35:34 1.17973ms 127.0.0.1 - Qt Location based application 200 /route/v1/driving/-122.297,37.5467;-122.291,37.5443?overview=full&steps=true&geometries=polyline&alternatives=true[0m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug in QT, I had to download the source files, and rebuild it.

The bug is how the routingUrl appends the GPS lat/long in the request URL in the function QGeoRouteParserOsrmV5Private::requestUrl in file qgeorouteparseosrmv5.cpp